# Open CV mapping patch to image

Tags: python, opencv, affinetransform

I have the following situation, in which I have an heightmap, and several patches extracted after an affine mapping from it, then I have applied a color mapping to the patch, and now what I need to do is to blend the patch onto the heightmap at the corrected coordinates. How can I do this? Following is the function I use to do the transformation, basically I will need the inverse.

```
def extract_patch(image, center, theta, width, height):
    vx = (np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta))
    vy = (-np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta))
    sx = center[0] - vx[0] * (width / 2) - vy[0] * (height / 2)
    sy = center[1] - vx[1] * (width / 2) - vy[1] * (height / 2)

    mapping = np.array([[vx[0],vy[0], sx], [vx[1],vy[1], sy]])
    return cv2.warpAffine(image, mapping, (width, height), flags = cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP, borderMode = cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
```

[image: heightmap][image: patch]